# JWT token as an object

Tags: jwt

Is it required to return a JWT token as an object? Or better yet, what's the right way to return it?

In some examples, I see only the actual result being returned i.e. `"xxxxx.yyyyy.zzzzz"` and in other examples it's returned inside an object i.e.

```
{
   "token": "xxxxx.yyyyy.zzzzz"
}
```

I've also seen the following:

```
{
   "token": "xxxxx.yyyyy.zzzzz",
   "expires": "date-in-unix-time"
}
```

I suspect the above example with the `expires` property is a bit redundant because the expiration is already built into the token.

Nevertheless, which one of these is the right approach?

Comment: Is this regarding a particular JavaScript library?

Comment: No, just general purpose API that will respond to different types of clients. Just want to make sure I'm generating and returning the JWT token in the correct format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no set way to return a token. I attached a picture from [JWT.io](https://jwt.io/introduction/) that demonstrates this.

You can see that step 3 is rather non-commital. What's important is that the browser can use the token once it has been returned (step 4). Just be sure to follow your own standard and not to deviate from it.

If it were me, I'd put it in a JSON object. That way I can also return any other data inside the object alongside the token.

```
{
  "token": "x.y.z",
  "message": "Welcome back, Sam! That last time you logged in was in September.",
  "lastLoggedIn": "1505926800"
}
```

[image]